# How to detect overflow in a nested div (React)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I want to create a div, which shows blurr on the bottom of the div (when overflow exists). The issue is that the div contains props.children, which also consist of other components / html tags inside.

I tried using ref (React.useRef), but the ref is set even before the children are renderen. I tried using useEffect with the ref, but still when I use for example element.current.scrollbarHeight I get 0.

How can I check if the rendered div (with children) has overflow? (I am using a functional component)

```
<div> {props.children} </div>
```

For generating the blurr I am using styled-components.

Comment: Can you please share the all the code to be able to help?

Comment: Dear @KhaledAhmed, actually that <div>... is the only thing I need help with. The only thing there I added with styled-components is the height of the div, to 280px. I just want to find out if the props.children will cause an overflow. I do not know what will the props.children contain, it almost always has a different length and content.

Comment: I'm not sure it will ever be possible to know if arbitrary children are fully rendered without each one offering specialized callbacks. As such, it might be better to watch the element for size changes, by setting up something along the lines of the ResizeSensor in  https://github.com/marcj/css-element-queries in a `useEffect`

Comment: @spender the problem is, my div has a fixed size, and I want to find out if the contents of the div, the children, cause an overflow. I tried to put the useRef into the useEffect, and to track the changes, but for some reason, the height always stays 0.

Comment: You could however create a nest of 2 div. https://codesandbox.io/s/react-content-resized-detection-3f3gr . You're welcome. You'll want to check `scrollHeight` vs `offsetHeight` when you handle the `onContentResized` event. Let me know how you get on, and I'll make you a real answer if it helped.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will test it now, and I'll let you know if it works with the children elements! @spender

Comment: @spender Hi, I tested it, but still the same results that I had. It sends me back the message when the div resizes, but the scrollHeight still stays 0. I printed it out in onContentResized as you said.

Comment: I made some changes to better reflect usage and now pass a `hasOverflow` param in the `onContentResized`. Maybe that will help. https://codesandbox.io/s/react-content-resized-detection-3f3gr

Comment: @spender Thank you. I will test it now

Comment: @spender hi, thank you! This worked! Post it please as an answer so I can accept it as a solution.

Comment: Awesome. Lucky you caught me on a good day :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible to know if arbitrary children are fully rendered without each one offering specialized callbacks. As such, it might be better to watch elements for size changes.

We can use [`ResizeObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver) to our advantage here.

If we create a nested pair of div:

```
<div class="fixed_size_overflow_auto">
    <div>
        {children}
    </div>
</div>
```

making the outer div have fixed dimensions, we can listen for resize on the inner div. When we detect those resizes, we can calculate if the outer div has overflowed by comparing its `offsetHeight` to its `scrollHeight`.

Here is the idea, wrapped up in a component that can be styled using `styled-components`:

```
const DetectContentResizeElement: FC<{
  className?: string;
  onContentResized?: (v: { hasOverflow: boolean }) => void;
}> = ({ children, onContentResized, className }) => {

  const contentRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
  const outerRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!contentRef.current || !outerRef.current) {
      return;
    }

    const obs = new ResizeObserver(() => {
      const hasOverflow =
        (outerRef.current?.offsetHeight ?? 0) <
        (contentRef.current?.offsetHeight ?? 0);
      onContentResized?.({ hasOverflow });
    });

    obs.observe(contentRef.current);
    return () => obs.disconnect();
  }, [onContentResized]);

  return (
    <div className={className} ref={outerRef}>
      <div ref={contentRef}>{children}</div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

You can fix the size of this component by "subclassing" it with styled-components:

```
const FixedHeight = styled(DetectContentResizeElement)`
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: solid 1px black;
  overflow: auto;
`;
```

so now you can use this container and get events that tell you when it overflowed:

```
  <FixedHeight
    onContentResized={({ hasOverflow }) =>
      console.log(`resized. hasOverflow: ${hasOverflow}`)
    }
  >
    <SomeChildElement />
  </FixedHeight>
```

See it in action in this [codesandbox project](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-content-resized-detection-3f3gr) (uses [resize-observer-polyfill ponyfill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/resize-observer-polyfill) for best compatibility)